# How can I compare struct data in two ordered arrays?

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, struct

I have an interesting problem. I'm creating a revisions system for my application. The way it works is that every time a new post object is created, the post object attempts to create a history record for each one of its attributes that has changed.

So if the post.subject was edited, a new revision record is created in a history table. It will only store the new subject text (as well as the associated post, and user who made it). If more than one attribute is changed, they're passed in an array and each attribute will be stored in its own record, grouped by a UUID.

To cut down on excess records, the history object will attempt to find any existing revisions and update them `if the existing revisions are younger than a certain time limit.` This way we can keep changes made in a short timespan in the same revision. If they're not younger, then new revisions are created.

**Scenario:**

1. User Foo changes the subject on a post (a subject revision is created).
2. User Foo goes back and changes the body and the subject (existing subject revision is updated; a new body revision is created). Both revisions would need to have the same UUID.

Each post object has three attributes `subject, body, footer`. I already did the easy part: Create new revisions if none exist by looping over the array of args that contains revision data.

```
// Find existing revisions younger than some time value
local.revisions = this.findAll(where="rules go here", returnAs="struct");

// If no revisions are found create new ones
if (! arrayLen(local.revisions))
{
    // Create UUID to group revisions
    local.revisionGUID = createUUID();

    // loop over the arguments array (contains revision data) and create new revisions
    for (local.i in arguments.data)
        local.history = this.new(properties=local.i, revisionGUID=local.revisionGUID);
        local.histroy.save();
}

// If some revision data does exist, update existing ones, and create the new ones; the UUID for new revisions should use the UUID of existing revisions
else
{
   logic goes here
}
```

Now for the tricky part. If an array of revisions does come back I need to do this:

1. Compare it to the array in the args scope.
2. For each revision in the args scope that does not exist in the existing revisions array, I need to create it. For revision in the args scope that does exist (meaning it has a matching revision under the age limit), I need to update its data with the data from the corresponding revision in the args scope.

It can't be as simple as an arrayContains() because the data stored in the arrays are structs.. I don't know how to compare arrays that contain structs!

**Question:**

1. Am I approaching the problem the right way?
2. What methods are available to me to complete the functionality mentioned above?

Comment: Use WDDX or JSON to serialize the structs inside the array and then do string comparison.

Comment: @orangepips would that work? would the struct keys be guaranteed ordered in WDDX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning:** This is highly experimental...

```
<cfset x1 = {a=1,b=2}>
<cfset x2 = {b=2,a=1}>

<cfdump var="#x1.hashCode()#">
<cfdump var="#x2.hashCode()#">
```

They return the same value.  So you may, if you like, use `hashCode()` to compare struct's using the underlying Java's method `public int hashCode()` of `java.lang.Object`

Comment: Yes, you might want to review the javadocs on that one first ;) I remember they surprised me http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29